# Different storyboards for different devices in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

In the new Xcode 6, we have just one storyboard for universal apps. But the differences in my app are beyond the different sizes of the screen between iPhone and iPad. My App iPhone screen does not rotate, it's just portrait, and my iPad screen rotate all. My iPhone first screen is a table view, and my iPad first screen is a collection view, and other differences.
How can I make it happen in Xcode 6?

In other words. At Xcode 5 even using universal apps, i have two storyboards, one for iPad and another for iPhone. But now, in Xcode 6, theres just one storyboard for universal apps. I want to have two storyboards again, but I didn't find how to do this.

Comment: I m no getting you, But you should create diff. story board for iPhone and iPad. And not for diff. iPhone screen size. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but english is not my native language. I'll try to explain it. At xcode 5 even using universal apps, i have two storyboards, one for iPad and another for iPhone. But now, in xcode 6, theres just one storyborad for universal apps. I want to have two storyboards again, but I didn't find how to do this.

Comment: Ok. Yes as Matt specified, you can still do it. But you need to manually configure it like what you have in Xcode 5.

Comment: I don't have level to put images at my question, but in Xcode 6 theres no fields to configure two storyborads like in Xcode 5. I've uploaded the prints in my Google Drive. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3Rrrm2gKi_JVDltVjFxdGpuWWc&usp=sharing

Comment: You are not listening to what @TechNet-Weblineindia is telling you. Look in the _Info.plist_ for your existing two-storyboard app. Configure the _Info.plist_ for your new app to look like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> At Xcode 5 even using universal apps, i have two storyboards, one for iPad and another for iPhone. But now, in Xcode 6, theres just one storyboard for universal apps. I want to have two storyboards again, but I didn't find how to do this.

Do it the same way you were doing it in Xcode 5. No law says you *have* to have just one storyboard in a universal app in Xcode 6. The old way works just fine. I have apps that still do this (recompiled in Xcode 6 for iOS 8); it works.

However, something odd is undoubtedly going on. Look at this screen shot. It shows two projects open simultaneously in Xcode 6. One shows the iPhone / iPad buttons for switching between settings within the Universal setting; the other doesn't. I can't find a difference between the two projects that causes this differing interface.

[image]

Comment: I don't have level to put images at my question, but in Xcode 6 theres no fields to configure two storyborads like in Xcode 5. I've uploaded the prints in my Google Drive. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3Rrrm2gKi_JVDltVjFxdGpuWWc&usp=sharing

Comment: I didn't say anything about fields. Those fields are just front ends for editing the _Info.plist_. Learn to edit the _Info.plist_ directly.

Comment: Besides you _can_ do it. Switch to iPhone and set the name of the storyboard for iPhone. Switch to iPad and set the name of the storyboard for iPad. Now switch to Universal. Do nothing. Done. Basically they've made the interface _easier_.

Comment: Or, make it totally automatic by using automatic names, e.g. `Main.storyboard` and `Main~ipad.storyboard`.

Comment: Okay so now I've given you _three_ different ways to set it up.

Comment: It's bizarre, but worked. I created a github project with step by step commits. thanks matt. https://github.com/alexandrenc/TwoStoryboards

Comment: Nevertheless I do see why you're confused. I'm confused too. See my addition to my answer.

Comment: I've filed a bug report on this. I can understand if they have abolished the iPhone / iPad buttons, but I do not see why those buttons sometimes appear and sometimes don't.

Answer (score 47):

1. Open your Project setting >> select info
2. In Custom iOS Target Properties add New row name Main storyboard file base name (iPad) and set value to "your new storyboard file name"

or 
You can find the way in my blog

[Xcode 6 Separate storyboard for iPad and iPhone](http://irawd.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/xcode-6-separate-storyboard-for-ipad-and-iphone/)