# How to create the old storyboard in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I need to create 2 separate storyboards for `iPads` and `iPhones`.
The `storyboards` in `Xcode 6` are universal in size and require constrains.
I need to have a one size `iPad storyboard` like the old ones, before you had constrains.

The problem is that if i add a new `storyboard`, i always get that new standard size `storyboard` where you have at the bottom : `w/any, h/any` .

How can you get that single size old storyboard for iPad where you dont have constrains, and you just drag and drop stuff and it fits all iPad sizes ?

I have read this but didn't help
[Different storyboards for different devices in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819141/different-storyboards-for-different-devices-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Utilities , uncheck Use Size Classes， this will bring you to older Stroyboard.However, Size Classes is the new features for grouping iPad and iPhone sizes in iOS 8. So why not having a try?

[image]

Comment: thanks, why not? because its too messy to really make one app to all devices. the aspect ratio is different and you cant even place your views so that they fit to your eyes as you wanted them. the universal view is a square and your UI is completely different-so you cant even drag and drop it to build a UI.