# How to arrange UI elements so they fit in all screen sizes in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been struggling with this issue for a while and hours of research and experimentation didn't produce any acceptable results.

I have a login screen that contains a lot of UI elements. The view looks great on iphone 7 and 6 variations but when I test it on SE or 4S the constraints fail to position the elements so they fit nicely on their tiny screen. Simply there is not enough room. I read that I must support all screen sizes but at this point I am not sure how can I get all the ui elements to fit in the smaller screens.
I watched hours of youtube videos and tried all possible ways including a vertical stack view but no matter what I try, it either looks good on 7 and 6 but terrible on SE/4S or vice versa (good on SE/4S but way too much white space on 7/6).

At this point I am not sure what else I can do. I know it is not possible to design a UI just for a specific screen size and vary for traits is not what I need because I only intend to support vertical orientation.

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're more likely to get a helpful response if you ask a specific question about your layout. If you provide screenshots and code showing what you've tried, someone is usually able to help.

Comment: will do! I'll work on it right away. thanks,

Comment: Have you tried using auto layout? It seems like a negligible amount of work to get the ui to look as intended.

Comment: yes I have. With auto layout i can get the ui to look great in iphone 7/6 but not for iphone 4s. When I switch to 4S some of the UI elements don't appear because , I am assuming, the screen is too small. Event if I try to set the constraints based on the edges of the screen, at some point they are going to overlap. so I'd love to know how you could get it look great on iphone 4s.

Comment: Making a UI that looks good on a 4S sized screen and a 7+ sized screen is hard. It's a design problem. In your case, you should be able to use some basic auto layout constraints to have everything appear on screen.

Comment: right. that's my point. I can either design it to look good on 4s or 6/7 but nt both. If I design it to look good on 4S then the result on 7/6 is a UI with lots of white space which looks ugly. Let me ask you this - is it possible to restrict my binary to only run on iphones 7 and 6? in other words, when I publish the app, I don't want to people who own 4S to be able to download my app.

Comment: it seems like you lose most of your real estate with that top image.  have you considered just changing that image to not take up so much vertical space?

Comment: I just realized that if I set my deployment target to 10.3 (which is the default in my case), iPhone 4s is not supported because it cannot run iOS 10.x     you guys should have told me that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have said in your own comment, you can restrict the device sizes indirectly by restricting the iOS version. However that is not a good solution: If you are creating the app for commercial reasons that will unnecessarily restrict your market (there are a lot of 4S users out there); If you are learning app development, now is a good time to work out how to manage GUI layout problems properly (there will always be a wide range of display sizes to cope with).

There are several tools available to assist:

**Auto Layout**

As others have said in comments, Auto Layout can help a lot. Don't just use it to position things though, but also to resize them to make best use of the available space.

[Understanding Auto Layout (Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/)

**Size Classes**

Size Classes allow you to use different constraints and turn on or off controls depending on the general size and orientation of your user's device. For example, where space is restricted you could hide individual controls and instead display a single control to take the user to them elsewhere (another view or a popover for example).

[Size-Class-Specific Layout (Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html)

**Scroll Views**

You can make part or all of your GUI a scroll view that on larger devices will show all the controls whilst on smaller devices initially show just the top ones but still give your users access to the others (don't forget to flash the scroll bars when the view first appears to show them that there is more to see though).

**Separate Storyboards**

Although you have not mentioned iPad support, you can also specify completely separate storyboards to help layout universal apps.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26494048/2466193) and it's linked reference for details.

Comment: Ali, Thank you so much. this was really helpful. I did not think about scroll view. That is actually a great idea. I've been developing apps for 3 years but always struggled with the more complex auto-layout features. For basic layout stuff, auto-layout is probably the best thing ever.   I know restricting devices is not a good practice, that's why I came to SO for help, even though, my boss told me not to worry about it because nobody in my company have 4S anymore. (the app is developed for an internal use) .  Again, thanks for all the great info.